# Final paper submission while NOT attending the conference

Tags: conference, paper-submission

I'm the corresponding author of my accepted paper in a conference. I won't be able to attend the conference so one of the co-authors will attend and present the paper.

Now for the final paper submission, I have to make a full registration for the system to let me upload the final version.

Should I register and upload the final paper while I know I'm not going to attend? I know that only the corresponding author can submit the final version.
Is it possible to register and then somehow transfer my submission to my co-author who will be attending or he needs to make a separate registration?

Comment: The answer to this question seems completely dependent on the specific conference and their procedures...

Comment: What I did before for an IEEE conference is that I asked the presenting author to register for the conference and then I uploaded the Manuscript through my account using a code he recieved. He presented the paper. No issues, it's normal. Now depending on your conference,  it may be the same procedure and maybe not. So check with them. Cheers.

Comment: @Pioneer83 Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mohammad, your co-author can attend the conference on your behalf, as he/she is also the part of that paper. However, it's better to contact the convenor/organizer of that conference. It depends upon their policies whether they allow it or not.

Comment: That may or may not be true, depending on the conference. Someone has to pay, most likely, and credentials may not be transferrable. Contact the conference, as you say.

Answer (score 0):

This is highly conference-dependent, but in outline:

- Look up and carefully read any instructions provided by the conference — check both in emails/other correspondence, and on their website.
- If those instructions answer the question, great!
- If they’re unclear, email the conference’s enquiries/contact address to ask for clarification.  (This is the most likely outcome, I guess.)
- If they’re clear but you’ve ended up in a situation they don’t cover, perhaps due to an earlier mistake or a change of plans (e.g. if the corresponding author was supposed to be the presenting/attending author from the start), then email the conference’s enquiries/contact address, explaining the situation, apologising if appropriate, and asking what you should do now.